# Lighthouse not detecting service worker even though it shows in application

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

I have my PWA working. Manifest is detected, service worker gets registered.

However, Lighthouse is seeming to fail to detect the service worker.
It says

```
Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url
This origin has one or more service workers, however the page (https://beegle.app/beeglepro) is not in scope.
```

However, I am indeed registering the service worker and with a scope. The scope and start url are mentioned in the manifest too.

You can check my pwa at https://beegle.app/beeglepro and see the issue yourself.

Here's how the manifest file (https://beegle.app/bpro-manifest.json) looks like

```
{
  "name": "Beegle Pro",
  "short_name": "Beegle Pro",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "/beegle-logo-128x128.png",
    "sizes": "128x128",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-152x152.png",
    "sizes": "152x152",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-512x512.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "start_url": "/beeglepro/",
  "scope": "/beeglepro/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "theme_color": "#DEEC02"
}
```

Here's how the service worker is being invoked:

```
<script src="/bpro-install.js"></script>
<script>
// CODELAB: Register service worker.
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/bpro-service-worker.js', {
  scope: '/beeglepro/'})
        .then((reg) => {
          console.log('Service worker registered.', reg);
        });
  });
}
</script>
```

Could someone please suggest what could be going wrong?

I don't know how to mention start-url in service worker. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Have you solved it? Same problem here

Comment: By the way, I checked your website and ran Lighthouse, and the problem still persists. The question is: is that a real PWA/Service worker problem or just the Lighthouse throws the error because the service worker is not in the root of the webapp ('/')? The same problem happens here: PWA is not in the root ('/'), everything got installed but the Lighthouse throws the same error. I didn't found nothing in internet about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guessing here but is the path to your assets missing "assets"?

```
  "src": "assets/beegle-logo-128x128.png",
```